# New line after foreach loop

Tags: c#, loops, newline

This code works as it should

```
foreach (char c in partToDecode)
{
    var sum = c - 48;
    if (sum > 40)
    {
        sum = sum - 8;
    }

    string suma = Convert.ToString(sum, 2).PadLeft(6, '0');
    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\jakub\Pulpit\binary.txt", suma);
}
```

We're inside invisible for i loop (i meant that foreach and this newline is inside of for loop named I) so I need a new line in for loop after foreach loop.
This code isn't working as i wish to, i've got a new line at the beginning and in 2nd line a plain text, the desire is to have a new line after each finish of the foreach loop

```
        string sumaaa = Convert.ToString(sum, 2).PadLeft(6, '0');
        File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\jakub\Pulpit\binary.txt", sumaaa);
    }

    FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\jakub\Pulpit\binary.txt", FileMode.Open);
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream);
    sw.Write("\n");
    sw.Close();
}
```

This is kinda small, after that I have a code for splitting bits to convert small pieces of it to decimal. It worked earlier but i inserted it inside a comment and now it writes nothing. This loop stands alone after all, runs after clicking ok, then i have a form2 which is displayed always, no errors.

```
for (var k = 0; k < binlines.Count(); k++)
{       
    var binline = binlines[k];
    if (binline != null) //in case it was an empty line error (it's not)
    { 
        string partmessage = binline.Substring(0, 6);
        string partdecoded = Convert.ToInt32(partmessage, 2).ToString();
        string partmessage2 = binline.Substring(6, 2);
        string partdecoded2 = Convert.ToInt32(partmessage2, 2).ToString();
        string partmessage3 = binline.Substring(8, 30);
        string partdecoded3 = Convert.ToInt32(partmessage3, 2).ToString();
        string so on to 15
        File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\jakub\Pulpit\decimal.txt", partdecoded + "," + partdecoded2 + "," partdecoded3 + "," + partdecoded4...)
    }
    else
    {
    }
```

Now i've got an exception of out of range "index and length must reference to location in string"

Comment: What is "invisible for i loop"?

Comment: @Charlieface: Clarified in post, just a not closed for loop above

Comment: `File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\jakub\Pulpit\binary.txt", suma + Environment.NewLine);`?

Comment: Maybe it would help if you show the actual format you want, and the format you are getting (when its nearly working) and the code that produces that

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: you mean inside a foreach loop? It's going to add a new line after each char transformed to binary. I need a new line after each partToDecode variable (it's looped)

Comment: `AppendAllText` does not add a newline by default. Why are you using `AppendAllText` as well as `FileStream`, stick to one. If using `FileStream` make sure to put in `using` block

Comment: I see, so there's an outer for loop you haven't included? Can you put `File.AppendAllText(Environment.NewLine);` after the closing brace for your `c` loop and before the closing brace for your `i` loop?

Comment: "It worked earlier but i inserted it inside a comment and now it writes nothing." This makes it sound like you commented out the code (`/* */`) and now you're surprised that it's not executing. Could you clarify?

Comment: @00110001: 
So a foreach is going through banch of chars from string like dDP(28 chars)...
It's changing it to 010011100110011011(so on 168 digits in each string)...  When foreach loop is finished one time we have 168 digits and i want a new line exactly now. 
Clear?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: I'm not that stupid, it's there already. Inside I, after C
I don't know what happend, I moved it to an appropriate position. Curly braces are ok, nothing happened. 
I started to  work with file.append becouse it's easy to do

Comment: So you are trying to convert, a string representation of binary to a comma separated file of integers ?

Comment: @00110001: exactly, commas becouse of easier way to get it out of file later.
But for now i have a plain text of 01 instead of lines.
Probably there's a better way to do this than substring

Comment: Are you reading this data out in C#, or is another application. I mean when you generate the CSV, is it for human eyes, another application, or an application you wrote ?

Comment: The reason i ask, is because, there is no need to bother with lines, Just write the data format in the native int32 type to file. You know how many elements in each bunch of data. so you know how many 4 bytes chunks to read. In that case you can just use BinaryReader and BinaryWriter.

Comment: Ill write up an example

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not using a csv format to start with, and write your native binary data to disk. In that case you could just use BinaryReader and BinaryWriter that makes this trivial.

Also it probably worth making some healper methods or a class that can take care of the reading of binary data to int.

**Given**

```
public struct BinReader
{
   private readonly string _line;
   private int _index;
   public BinReader(string line)
   {
      _line = line;
      _index = 0;
   }
   public int GetInt(int length)
   {
      var result = Convert.ToInt32(_line.Substring(_index, length), 2);
      _index += length;
      return result;
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
// some test data
var binLines = new List<string>()
{
   Convert.ToString(1, 2) + Convert.ToString(2, 2) + Convert.ToString(3, 2) + Convert.ToString(4, 2) + Convert.ToString(5, 2),
   Convert.ToString(1, 2) + Convert.ToString(2, 2) + Convert.ToString(3, 2) + Convert.ToString(4, 2) + Convert.ToString(5, 2),
};


// write to file
using (var sw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream("SomeFileName.dat", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)))
{
   foreach (var reader in binLines.Select(line => new BinReader(line)))
   {
      sw.Write(reader.GetInt(1));
      sw.Write(reader.GetInt(2));
      sw.Write(reader.GetInt(2));
      sw.Write(reader.GetInt(3));
      sw.Write(reader.GetInt(3));
   }
}

// read from file
using (var br = new BinaryReader(new FileStream("SomeFileName.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)))
{
   foreach (var reader in binLines.Select(line => new BinReader(line)))
   {
      Console.WriteLine(br.ReadInt32());
      Console.WriteLine(br.ReadInt32());
      Console.WriteLine(br.ReadInt32());
      Console.WriteLine(br.ReadInt32());
      Console.WriteLine(br.ReadInt32());
   }
}
```

**Proof it works**

```
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Well, sometimes I don't know it's length, it all depends from a sorted out message. I'll show you a whole code
https://pastebin.com/fW2H4nQr
So the first part is an show dialog action, then entering a txt with !AIVDM1,1,,1,A,actualmessage,6

Comment: @Jacob2396 i see. I am not sure this answer helps you all that much, anyway good luck

Comment: yeah, it's useful i think to a second part. 
Don't you know what to do to get this new line? It's crucial to get it. I was thinking about some loop in foreach loop but i'm not into all methods so don't know how to do something like this.  (probably for instead foreach) 
`StringBuilder sb = ...
sb.append(sum);
if (parttodecode.count = parttodecode.length)
{
File.AppendAllText(path, sb.tostring() + "\n")
`
}
Do you see an option to do something like this?